# PHP check in array if timeslot has been taken

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How do I check if certain timeslot within range start to finish has been taken.

I highlighted the problem (image).

1. Timeslot: 00:00 - 00:45
2. Timeslot: 03:00 - 06:00
3. Timeslot: 05:00 - 10:00 (this should check that it must greater than 06:00)

HTML mark up

```
 #option value: 00:00 till 23:45 with 15 minutes gaps
 <select name="start_time[]"></select>
 <select name="finish_time[]"></select>
```

PHP:

```
if ( is_array($_POST['start_time']) ) {

  $json_combine = array_combine($_POST['start_time'], $_POST['finish_time']);

  foreach ($json_combine as $jcs => $jcf ) {
    if ( ($jcs > $jcf) OR ($jcs == $jcf) ) {
       echo 'Start time must before finish time.';
       break;
    }
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: please share your drop down values?

Comment: @raveenanigam its times value from 00:00 to 23:45

Comment: have you tried in_array function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a DateTime for the comparision:

```
if ( is_array($_POST['start_time']) ) {
    $json_combine = array_combine($_POST['start_time'], $_POST['finish_time']);

    foreach ($json_combine as $jcs => $jcf ) {
        $d1=new DateTime($jcs);
        $d2=new DateTime($jcf);
        if ($d1 >= $d2) {
            echo 'Start time must before finish time.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this if i correctly understood it :

```
foreach ($_POST['start_time'] as $index => $key) {

    $start_time = strtotime($_POST['start_time'][$index+1]);
    $finish_time = strtotime($_POST['finish_time'][$index]);

    if ( ($start_time > $finish_time) OR ($start_time == $finish_time) ) {
       echo 'Start time must before finish time.';
       break;
  }

}
```